# Get the number before a certain value in each row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I haven't be able to find this anywhere. I want to be able to create a column that uses the data from the column before the column that contains "end".

I may not even be explaining that well.

For Example:

```
df =

V1     V2  V3     V4     V5   V6
 0  start   1    end  ended    0
 3    end   0  start      5    0
 2  start   3   next      6  end
```

I want the new column to be the number before the following column says "end".

```
V1     V2  V3     V4     V5   V6  end_num
 0  start   1    end  ended    0        1
 3    end   0  start      5    0        3
 2  start   3   next      6  end        6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution in `base R`:

```r
df$end_num <- apply(df, 1, \(x) x[which(x == "end") - 1])
df

#>   V1    V2 V3    V4    V5  V6 end_num
#> 1  0 start  1   end ended   0       1
#> 2  3   end  0 start     5   0       3
#> 3  2 start  3  next     6 end       6
```

Answer (score 7):

A `base` solution using `max.col()` to find the position of *"end"* for each row:

```r
df$end_num <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df == "end", "first") - 1)]

df
#   V1    V2 V3    V4    V5  V6 end_num
# 1  0 start  1   end ended   0       1
# 2  3   end  0 start     5   0       3
# 3  2 start  3  next     6 end       6
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 3L, 2L), V2 = c("start", "end", "start"),
V3 = c(1L, 0L, 3L), V4 = c("end", "start", "next"), V5 = c("ended", "5", "6"),
V6 = c("0", "0", "end")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

---

###### Benchmark

```r
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 1e7, TRUE), 1e5, 1e2))
df[cbind(1:1e5, sample(2:100, 1e5, TRUE))] <- 'end'

library(microbenchmark)

bm <- microbenchmark(
  Darren = {
    df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df == "end", "first") - 1)]
  }, PaulS = {
    apply(df, 1, \(x) x[which(x == "end") - 1])
  }, check = 'identical'
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  Darren 264.9914 279.1987 300.9004 291.2345 309.7278  392.2026   100
#   PaulS 833.3212 919.4272 948.9276 955.9418 985.1518 1069.0307   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a some kind of laborious `tidyverse` solution: :-)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(. == "end" ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  mutate(New_Col = paste0("V", parse_number(New_Col)-1)) %>% 
  mutate(end_num = purrr::map2_chr(row_number(),New_Col,~df[.x,.y]), .keep="unused")
```

```
  V1    V2 V3    V4    V5  V6 end_num
1  0 start  1   end ended   0       1
2  3   end  0 start     5   0       3
3  2 start  3  next     6 end       6
```

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution: pivoting your dataframe into a long format, creating a new grouping column to ID the first and second columns, then summarise by row.

One nice feature about this approach is that you can identify if any rows have multiple instances of "end".

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(0, 3, 2),
  V2 = c("s", "e", "s"),
  V3 = c(1, 0, 3),
  V4 = c("e", "s", "n"),
  V5 = c("en", 5, 6),
  V6 = c(0, 0, "e")
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_pivot <- df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> # need a row number to unpivot
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(everything(), -id), names_pattern = "(\\d+)", # don't pivot id
    names_transform = list(name = as.integer), values_transform = as.list
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    col_rem = name %% 2,
    col_group = (name + col_rem) / 2, # round up to lowest divisible by 2
    col_type = ifelse(col_rem == 0, "second", "first")
  ) |> 
  select(-col_rem, -name) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_type, values_from = value) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  summarise(
    new = first[second == "e"]
  )
```